# i have multiple duplicate rows in sqlite i want to delete only 1 row at one time

Tags: sqlite

i have this this table

col1    col2    col3    ...   col50
1       jim     red           1jimred
1       jim     red           1jimred
1       jim     red           1jimred
1       jim     red           1jimred
2       sam     blue          1samblue
3       fox     pink          3foxpink

And i want this

col1    col2    col3    ...   col50
1       jim     red           1jimred
1       jim     red           1jimred
1       jim     red           1jimred
2       sam     blue          1samblue
3       fox     pink          3foxpink

Answer (score 0):

It's not usually a good design idea to have duplicate rows in a table.

Given you have them, many SQLITE tables have a ROWID column - that column contains a unique number by which you can differentiate the otherwise identical rows.

On the other hand, if you deliberately created the table with the option WITHOUT ROWID, youd task is much harder :)

Comment: Actually i am making cart table where we add multiple same items and also increment and decrement so i need delete one time one row.

Comment: Adding items to a cart is not the same as adding rows to table. The rows need to be uniquely identifiable in some way (unlike  fungible cart items) to do what you want easily. The built-in ROWID is designed for that purpose. Use it, or come up with your own method of adding a unique value somehow.,,,,Relational databases are intended for SETs not BAGs, mathematically. https://mednoter.com/what-is-the-difference-between-set-bag-and-list.html